# Chrome DevTools - SQL query not executed

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I try to execute an SQL query with Chrome DevTools for an Android app, but it's not possible, because enter button moves the cursor to the next line instead of executing a commend. It worked some time ago.

I reinstalled Chrome, removed all Chrome data and reinstalled, used Chromium browser, but still no result.

All the other functions of DevTools are working correctly, e.g. networking, database preview.

It's happening with different apps and devices.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/929636.

Comment: @wOxxOm exactly, it's the same bug

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in new versions of Chrome. So far, the only workaround I found is to download an earlier version, 71, for example from here:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

You can look here for a detailed discussion:
https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/634